# How to remove undeletable USB drive partition

Tags: mac, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, file-management

I received a free 2 GB USB from my school and was wondering if I can remove the small partition of 6 MB that they reserved to store a html file that will take me to a website link for information regarding the school.

Is there a workaround for removing the 6 MB partition?

Comment: I haven't tried anything but to try to delete it normally.

Comment: Can you mark something as solution, or did you find any by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You need a linux system for my solution, but a linux system helps very often.

Backup all your data from that drive, we will overwrite it.

Find the device using `blkid`

It will be like `/dev/sdd`.

Now run:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=4M count=10
```

This will overwrite the partition table and the first 40MB.
After doing this, just create the partitioning the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Run disk management and delete the partition.  It seems like you can access the partition so disk management shouldn't have any problems.